# "Scheduled on" vs "scheduled for"

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between the following two expressions:

> My interview is scheduled **on** the 27th of June at 8:00 AM.
>
> My interview is scheduled **for** the 27th of June at 8:00 AM.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The version with *on* looks a little wrong to me. I would use *on* if I were describing the time at which the schedule was set, giving something like:

> My interview was scheduled **on** the 26th of June **for** the 27th of June at 8:00 AM.

This sentence means that on the 26th, two people agreed, "let's have an interview tomorrow." The 27th is when the interview (presumably) actually took place.

However, browsing google, it appears that **on** is sometimes (less frequently, but frequently enough) used for both senses. I suppose with enough context the meaning is clear, although I still prefer **for** in the original examples since it is not vague. Also, as J.R. pointed out in the comments, dropping *scheduled* makes **on** the only correct choice.

Comment: _On_ would work fine if the word _scheduled_ was removed: "My interview is on the 27th of June."

Comment: I have a hotel reservation for New Year's Eve. My reservation for New Year's Eve was scheduled on July 4th.  I'll use my reservation on New Year's Eve.

Comment: I know definitely it should be *for* if the time after *scheduled* refers to when the scheduled thing will happen. Having read Cameron's answer, I notice that *on* might also be correct but the meaning is different. Steve H's example clearly explains it as well. In addition, I agree to J.R.'s comment.

Comment: What probably causes some people to confuse 'scheduled on' with 'scheduled for' is that 'scheduled for the 27th of June' expresses the same thought as 'scheduled to take place **on** the 27th of June'.