# Looking for a word describing the date a payment was intended for

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm writing an application that currently stores the date that a payment was made as "CreatedOn". That date is always going to be what ever the time and date is at the time you made the payment.

The user can back-date payments. I'm not sure what word I should use to describe that. I initially was going to use PaymentDate, but that can be interpretted as the date that the payment was actually made on, rather than the date it was intended for.

Is there a word that I can use that will indicate that this payment was meant to be consumed on the date assigned to it? It's not really a due date or a target date. Date intended maybe? Ideally it would be one or two words that I can put together to indicate that this payment was intended for a different date than the date it was originally generated on.

All of the payments for the month is consolidated and a check is cut at the end of the month. So I could make a payment today, for today. Then make a payment tomorrow, for work performed two weeks ago during the same billing period.

Comment: Date assigned??

Comment: Why won't `target date` work?  From your description is sounds like the payment is targeted to a specific date.

Comment: Target Date could probably work, I was just asking if there is a literal word, or term I could use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Settlement date*. None of the regular dictionaries seem to have it, but ones focusing on English business jargon do.

[**The Free Dictionary**](http://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Settlement+Date)

> The date on which payment is made to settle a trade.

[**Investopedia**](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/settlementdate.asp)

> ...the date by which a buyer must pay for the securities delivered by the seller

The latter example highlights one issue with the term, though: it's primarily used for when a payment is made to purchase a security (i.e., a stock or bond).

Comment: I've updated my OP with an example use-case. If the check is cut at the end of the month when the billing period is over, would the check-cutting date be considered the settlement date, while the date the payment was intended for being considered something else, like **reckon** recommended by @ScottM?

Comment: Under those circumstances I would suggest **Transaction Date** rather than **reckon**. In finance that's the date in which the transaction is initiated, as opposed to the **Settlement Date** being the date in which it is finalized.

Comment: I think Transaction Date make sense.

Answer (score 9):

If the payment date must be stored discretely from the date the payment was applied to the application, *[backdate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/backdate?q=backdate)* is a direct reference to the action described:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT] British 1 Make (something, especially a pay increase)
>   retrospectively valid:
>   *the 4 per cent increase was **backdated** to June*
>
> <sub>ODO ***emphasis*** added</sub>

---

Alternately, *[reckon date](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reckon)* could work:

> verb
>
> 1 [WITH OBJECT] Establish by calculation:
>   *his debts were **reckoned** at
>   £300,000
>
>   the Byzantine year was **reckoned** from 1 September*
>
> <sub>ODO ***emphasis*** added</sub>

The payment was submitted on February 18, but it was reckoned for February 1.

Comment: I have updated my OP with a small example. It sounds like **reckon** is what I want in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the phrase "scheduled payment" or something with "scheduled" in it.
If you were willing to consider replacing "CreatedOn" with "ScheduledOn" (for the date of payment) you could use "ScheduledFor" for the intended date, along the lines of [this ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72122/scheduled-on-vs-scheduled-for/72123#72123).
Even without changing "CreatedOn," "ScheduledFor" for the intended date could work.

Comment: Please offer answers, not opinions (i.e. your answer should not contain a question mark; it should contain an assertion, backed up by external authorities, like dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

TenderDate, EffectiveDate, and CheckDated would be good options.  I disagree with using BackDate because it's inaccurate or inapplicable if the payment is not back dated. Be careful with Tender as it could have a special meaning in the context of some payment systems (e.g. equities).